# Is there any way to implement system() function

Tags: c, linux, unix

I tried to re-implement the system() library function. But I am not getting the output if i pass ps or ls command as an argument from the main. Thanks.

Original code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<error.h>
#define buf_size 512

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t pid;
    char *buf[buf_size];
    int ret = 0;
    char ch;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    if (argc != 2)
        error(1, 0, "Too many of less number of arguments\n");

    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        *(buf + j) = argv[i];
        j++;
    }
    buf[j] = '\0';
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) {
        error(1, 0, "error in creating the sub-process\n");
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        execv("bin/sh", buf);
    } else {
        wait(NULL);
    }
}
```

Edited code after reading some comments in this post:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t pid;
    int ret;

    if (argc != 2)
        error(1, 0, "Too many of less number of arguments\n");
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) {
        error(1, 0, "error in creating the sub-process\n");
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        ret = execv("/bin/sh", argv);
        if (ret == -1)
            error(1, 0, "error in execv() system call\n");
    } else {
        wait(NULL);
    }
}
```

Comment: `buf[j] = '\0';` doesn't make sense, it should be `buf[j] = NULL;`  It will work, but it's misleading, since you're using `'\0'` as a pointer.

Comment: You should test that `bin/sh` exist (what about `/bin/sh`)

Comment: Add some `perror("...");` after the `execv`: if it fails, you will get a beginning of explanation

Comment: The amount of editing the original poster has done to this post has made these comments and the answer below to be completely irrelevant. I'm ad ding the original code to the post so all this make sense again.

Comment: Warning about the `argv` using: what is the first argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were not far from the solution.

The main thing you miss is that you should have launch `/bin/sh -c ls` instead of `bin/sh ls`

The corrections:

- do not write `buf[j] = "\0";`, instead I increased the for loop size (notice the `i<= argc`)
- launch `/bin/sh` (forgot leading `/`)
- add `sh` and `-c` to `sh` options. (see man execv)

---

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<error.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t pid;
    char * buf[4];

    if (argc != 2)
        error(1, 0, "Too many of less number of arguments\n");

    buf[0] = "sh";
    buf[1] = "-c";
    buf[2] = argv[1];
    buf[3] = NULL;

    pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) {
        error(1, 0, "error in creating the sub-process\n");
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        execv("/bin/sh", buf);
        perror("execv"); 
   } else {
        wait(NULL);
    }
}
```

Comment: OP had `'\0'`, not `"\0"`.  They are very different.  Neither was correct, but I don't believe what OP had would actually result in a bug.